# Is the tag 'web-scrapping' really correct?

Tags: discussion

I recently used the tag [web-scrapping](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-scrapping), having first read it as 'web-scraping'. I realised it actually says 'web-*scrapping*'. Since I guess that does not really make sense, I guess it is a typo? Can we change the tag into 'web-scraping'? Or is 'web-*scrapping*' actually a thing?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I renamed it. Thanks. Could take a moment to update.